# How do I install and use a constant MethodHandle in ByteBuddy?

Tags: java, byte-buddy, methodhandle

I'm playing with the [support that ByteBuddy has for constant `MethodHandle`s](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.16/net/bytebuddy/utility/JavaConstant.MethodHandle.html#ofLoaded-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-).

I am trying to (effectively) look up a `MethodHandle` on one class, and then use it from a ByteBuddy-generated subclass.

(I am aware that I could do this using a static `MethodHandle` field and a type initializer, but I wanted to try it using this constant support.)

I have a `FieldDescription.Token` representing a field in the first class, and a `TypeDescription` representing the first class.  From these I can get a `FieldDescription.InDefinedShape` like this: `new FieldDescription.Latent(typeDescription, fieldDescriptionToken)`.  From *that* I can get a `JavaConstant.MethodHandle` like this: [`JavaConstant.MethodHandle.ofSetter(fieldDescriptionLatent)`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.16/net/bytebuddy/utility/JavaConstant.MethodHandle.html#ofSetter-net.bytebuddy.description.field.FieldDescription.InDefinedShape-).  This works fine.

Then I do this:

```
// Call invokeExact() on the MethodHandle I looked up, but
// call it on that MethodHandle as a constant pool entry.
builder
  .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(INVOKE_EXACT)
             .on(new JavaConstantValue(javaConstantMethodHandle),
                 MethodHandle.class)
             // etc.
```

By doing this, I am using the [`on` overload that takes a `StackManipulation`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.16/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.WithoutSpecifiedTarget.html#on-net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.StackManipulation-java.lang.Class-), which in this case is the `JavaConstantValue` which wraps a `JavaConstant`, which is a superclass of `JavaConstant.MethodHandle`.  As you can see, I am attempting to call `invokeExact()` on this `MethodHandle` where the `MethodHandle` is hopefully stored as a constant.

My first question is: **is this the right recipe?**

Next, the (stupid) field I am going to set in the superclass using this "field setter" `MethodHandle` is named `fortyTwo` and has a type of `Integer`.  You can probably guess what I want to set its value to.  This is all fine, and obviously doesn't (yet) have anything to do with ByteBuddy, but it will.

Everything compiles fine.

When I run my code, before I ever get a chance to do anything, i.e. during class load, I get a `ClassFormatError` for the generated subclass that ByteBuddy generates.  The error complains that this *subclass* has attempted to define a field (!) with an invalid signature:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Field "fortyTwo" in class com/foo/bar/GeneratedSubclassOf$com$foo$bar$Baz$26753A95 has illegal signature "V"
```

I am not defining such a field.  The superclass does, of course (see above), and its type, as previously noted, is `java.lang.Integer`.  The access level of the field does not matter.

I have looked at the `TypeDescription` contained by the `DynamicType.Unloaded` (before it is loaded, obviously) and there are no `fieldTokens`, i.e. ByteBuddy is truly not attempting to actually define a field in the subclass.  It appears that something in the recipe I'm using makes it look to the…uh, verifier? I guess? don't really know? that the `MethodHandle` represented by the constant is trying to manipulate the field on the *subclass*, and of course no such field exists (I'm going to guess that "`V`" is the bytecode signature for `void` and is probably the default).

So my last question is: **Why *does* the use of a field-setting `MethodHandle` constant make it *look like* ByteBuddy is attempting to define a field in the subclass in this case?**  It's as if the owning type of the field is dropped when the constant is defined or stored or something.

I presume this all has to do with how ByteBuddy supports constant `MethodHandle`s.  Could it be that ByteBuddy is not properly representing this kind of constant `MethodHandle` in the constant pool?  Or is this some sort of inherent problem with (maybe just field-setting) `MethodHandle`s themselves?

I do notice that [there is a reference (indirectly) to `void` in the ByteBuddy code in question](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/2255c3b04d10ae2d2b8bf8d00167f91b8ca67381/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/utility/JavaConstant.java#L616-L628).  This makes a certain amount of sense to me: if you're going to synthesize a method handle that sets a field, then its return type will be `void`.  I wonder though (naïvely) if this is in fact the proper type to pass here, or if this may be near where the problem lies.

On the other hand, it appears that in order to resolve a method handle constant that (in this case) is a "field setter", or [a method handle of kinds 1 through 4, inclusive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.5-220), [resolution must proceed according to the JVM's rules of field resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.5-240).  Those rules seem (to this naïve reader) to [indicate that the descriptor used should be the field's descriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.2).  I *think* that, instead, ByteBuddy [is using the descriptor of the synthesized method handle](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/2255c3b04d10ae2d2b8bf8d00167f91b8ca67381/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/utility/JavaConstant.java#L696) which in this case would be `V` (or `void`).  My naïve reading makes me think that at least in the case of "field setters" the return value of `getDescriptor()` should instead be the type of the sole parameter present in the return value of `getParameterTypes()`.

My apologies if I have misdiagnosed this; I am still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity: this turns out to be a bug in ByteBuddy [for which I've submitted a PR](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/pull/951).